# Can you filter querysets by user in models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I suppose the proper way to filter objects by user is done in views because you can easily require login and you have access to `request.user`. But I have a view that invokes the object's classmethod, which can't be combined with a filter because it converts the queryset to a list object- so I'm thinking if there's a way to filter the queryset by user directly in models, then when I invoke the classmethod in views the objects will already be filtered.

Here's my view:

```
def leads_by_city(request):
    # Invoke Lead classmethod to get the data
    data = Lead.objects.get_leads_per_city()

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Model with custom Manager:

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    source = models.ForeignKey(LeadSource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    objects = LeadManager()


class LeadManager(models.Manager):

    def get_leads_per_city(self):
        queryset = self.values('city').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('city')
        data = list(queryset.values('city', 'id__count'))

        return data
```

Is there a way to filter by user in the classmethod? Maybe like:

```
class LeadManager(models.Manager):

    def get_leads_per_city(self,user):
        queryset = self.filter(user=Lead.user).values('city').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('city')
        data = list(queryset.values('city', 'id__count'))

        return data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although your filtering is a bit off, you can simply set `.filter(user=user)`:

```
class LeadManager(models.Manager):

    def get_leads_per_city(self, user):
        queryset = self.filter(
            user=user
        ).values('city').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('city')
        return list(queryset.values('city', 'id__count'))
```

The `user=user` parameter name does *not* refer to the `user` parameter of the function. The Django ORM will look for a field with that name, and we pass it the `user` of the parameter call.

In your view, you can then call this with:

```
def leads_by_city(request):
    # Invoke Lead classmethod to get the data
    data = Lead.objects.get_leads_per_city(request.user)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

That being said, you here use Django's `QuerySet` mechanism to generate dictionaries. That is typically *not* advisable. You might want to use a [`Serializer`, as is offered by the Django REST Framework [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Furthermore it also is not a good idea to pass a list as a JSON response. There have been [JSON exploits](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/) with that, you better wrap this in a dictionary.

Since you require the logged in user, it might also be better to add the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) here, which will return a HTTP redirect response, given the user has not been logged in:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def leads_by_city(request):
    # Invoke Lead classmethod to get the data
    data = Lead.objects.get_leads_per_city(request.user)
    return JsonResponse({'data': data})
```

Comment: Willem thanks for that! It works but I'm not getting a list now, I need to make sure the user column doesn't contain null values. And I was planning on implementing REST framework at some point, I didn't know it wasn't good to use queryset for dictionaries so I'll go ahead and do that 

Comment: How would one achieve user filtering with DRF and Serializers then?